# Pointer arithmetic with multidimensional array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Consider this program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () { 
     unsigned int x [4] [3] = 
     {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}};
     printf ("Multidimensional array : %u, %u", x + 3, *(x + 3));

     // unsigned int* y[]={*x,*(x+1),*(x+2),*(x+3)};
    // printf("\nArray of pointers : %u %u",y + 3,*(y + 3));

  }
```

Output of this program is

> Multidimensional array : 1382418564, 1382418564

Since 'x+3' evaluates to '1382418564' , why *(x+3) is printing the same address again, instead of printing the value at that location ?

Comment: Never saw that, anyway thanks.

Comment: also... better to use `%p` to print out pointers instead of `%u`